# GLFW Window Creation Fails After glfwWindowHint() calls

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to create a window using GLFW3.  When I do this on my desktop, it works fine.  On my laptop, it fails to create a window, and the program crashes.  Removing the glfwWindowHint() calls prevents the crash, but my code doesn't work because I get the wrong version of openGL.  Here is the window code:

```
Window::Window(int width, int height, std::string title, bool full)
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    m_width = width;
    m_height = height;
    if (full)
    {
        m_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr);
    }
    else
    {
        m_window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(m_window);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

}
```

Might this have to do with the fact that my desktop has NVidia graphics while my laptop has integrated graphics?

Update:
It crashes on a call to glfwSwapBuffers(), and I have glfw error 65543 printed to the console.
glfwCreateWindow() is returning NULL;

Comment: How does your program crash?  Is it in one of the `glfw` calls and if so, which one?  Can you get a stack dump from the crash?

Comment: Does your laptop support OpenGL 4.1 or greater?  Any reason you aren't using [the GLFW debug callback](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__error.html#gaa5d796c3cf7c1a7f02f845486333fb5f)?

Comment: If you are running on onboard cards it is likely it doesn't support GL4.1

Comment: It crashes because the window is null.  Also, it doesn't work with OpenGL 3.3 either.  This version uses 4.1 because it runs on my desktop.

Comment: i have the same issue, my pc support only OpenGL 3.1 or lower, how can i get the version that work with my pc ? i prefer OpenGL 2.

Answer (score 0):

If it prints error 65543 to the console, that's equivalent to 0x00010007, which is defined in glfw3.h as GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE.

```
/*! @brief The requested OpenGL or OpenGL ES version is not available.
 *
 *  The requested OpenGL or OpenGL ES version (including any requested context
 *  or framebuffer hints) is not available on this machine.
 *
 *  @par Analysis
 *  The machine does not support your requirements.  If your application is
 *  sufficiently flexible, downgrade your requirements and try again.
 *  Otherwise, inform the user that their machine does not match your
 *  requirements.
 *
 *  @par
 *  Future invalid OpenGL and OpenGL ES versions, for example OpenGL 4.8 if 5.0
 *  comes out before the 4.x series gets that far, also fail with this error and
 *  not @ref GLFW_INVALID_VALUE, because GLFW cannot know what future versions
 *  will exist.
 */
#define GLFW_VERSION_UNAVAILABLE    0x00010007
```